# If column contains string, how do you add the column header onto a new column

Tags: r

Help! I'm trying to merge two files (both equal number of lines ~4,000) but one has a summary column and the other one doesn't, and I'm not sure how to go about it. Sorry, I'm new to R.

My logic is an IF statement on File B where if it column equals "yes" it prints column header to a new column also named "All_results" then merge the two files by "ID" and "All_results". Are there any suggested R functions to do this?

*******File A********

```
ID  All_results  cat  dog  fly
1  [cat, dog]     yes  yes  no
2  [cat]          yes  no  no
3  [cat, fly]     yes  no  yes
4  [dog]          no  yes  no
5  [dog, fly]     no  yes  yes
```

*****File B******

```
ID  lion  rat  frog
1   yes   yes  no
2   yes   no   no
3   yes   no   yes
4   no    yes  no
5   no    yes  yes
```

Expected outcome
******Merged_files********

```
ID  All_results         cat  dog  fly  lion  rat  frog
1  [cat,dog,lion,rat]   yes  yes  no    yes  yes  no
2  [cat,fly]            yes  no   no    yes  no   no
3  [cat, fly,lion,frog] yes  no   yes   yes  no   yes
4  [dog,rat]            no   yes  no    no   yes  no
5  [dog, fly,rat,frog]  no   yes  yes   no   yes  yes
```

Comment: Do you know how to merge the files? Then the rest can be done with `paste()` with the `collapse` option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Snoram! I was able to merge the files, but didn't know about paste() or collapse(). I'll look into those functions for future use. Its been difficult trying to find what I'm looking for when my R is very limited, so thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a pro in R myself, but this gave me the desired result. Hope it helps.

```
filea <- read.table( text = "ID  All_results  cat  dog  fly
1  \"[cat, dog]\"     yes  yes  no
2  \"[cat]\"          yes  no  no
3  \"[cat, fly]\"     yes  no  yes
4  \"[dog]\"          no  yes  no
5  \"[dog, fly]\"     no  yes  yes", header = TRUE)

fileb <- read.table(text = "ID  lion  rat  frog
                    1   yes   yes  no
                    2   yes   no   no
                    3   yes   no   yes
                    4   no    yes  no
                    5   no    yes  yes", header = TRUE)

fileab <- merge(filea[,-c(2)], fileb, by = "ID")

fileab$All_results <-  apply(fileab, 1, 
function(x) paste("[", paste(colnames(fileab)[x == "yes"], collapse = ","), "]", sep = ""))
```

Yielding this result

```
ID cat dog fly lion rat frog         All_results
1 yes yes  no  yes yes   no  [cat,dog,lion,rat]
2 yes  no  no  yes  no   no          [cat,lion]
3 yes  no yes  yes  no  yes [cat,fly,lion,frog]
4  no yes  no   no yes   no           [dog,rat]
5  no yes yes   no yes  yes  [dog,fly,rat,frog]
```

Update for case-insensitivity:

Insert this: `grepl("yes", x, ignore.case = T)`

```
fileab$All_results <-  apply(fileab, 1, function(x) paste("[", 
paste(colnames(fileab)[grepl("yes", x, ignore.case = T)], collapse = ","), "]", sep = ""))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much @Humpelstielzchen. Would you happen to know if x=="yes" can be case-insensitive in R?

Comment: I have made an update

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you! Appreciate this!